# Error: Exception thrown by the agent : java.net.MalformedURLException: Service URL contains non-ASCII character 0x968

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am creating a spring boot application but it is throwing this error while running it. I have no errors in my code. Can anyone help me out figuring out what this is! 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

glyph of 0x968, decimal 2408 from [ASCII table](https://asecuritysite.com/coding/asc2?val=2304%2C2560)

[image: glyph of 0x968, decimal 2408]

Assuming you are not trying to go to or load a URL containing that "non-ascii squiggle" character, the URL parser must be interpreting four bytes `0000100101101000` (0x0968) instead of two `00001001` (0x09 - TAB) and two `01101000` (0x68 - h).  Can you show the code that throws the MalformedURLException?  Can you URLEncode the string that contains the "non-ascii squiggle" bytes?  Can you remove the TAB character from the string?

Comment: Its a big project, so it would be difficult to show the code. But I figured out that while STS runs spring boot tommcat server it takes time into consideration and my time's ante meridiem and post meridiem are in Hindi. Can you help me figure out how can I change that, because everything else is in english and not these AM and PM

Comment: start here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23685129/am-pm-strings-not-localized-translated-when-using-dateformat   I think you are seeing the AM / PM symbols in your "default locale" - but I think you want the ASCII or UTF-8 symbols from the Europe or North America locales.

Comment: Thanks, It was just I need. @geneSummons